# CSS float property - Differences in behaviour when floating a div vs. floating a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm learning to use the CSS `float` property. I would like to make sense of a specific effect of this property.

Consider the following simple HTML elements:

```
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

And the following CSS rules:

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

If I `float: left` #div1, #div2 isn't visible anymore (because it is now hidden behind #div1).

I was expecting a similar thing would happen with the paragraph if I were to `float: left` #div2.

But this is not the case. The paragraph doesn't behave like the div. It doesn't hide behind #div2, but instead sits next to it.

Can somebody explain why there is this difference in behaviour?

Thank you.

Edit1:

Here is the Stacksnippet, with the initial code

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

Here is the snippet with a float: left declared in the #div1 CSS rule.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

And here is what happens when I use the same declaration in the #div2 rule:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Floating won't hide anything in sample code above. You have other styles involved.

Comment: Hello. I've been testing this code in Codepen. Here is a link to the pen in question (http://codepen.io/Baalinooo/pen/jVrGOw). If I add a float:left to #div1 (i.e. the blue square), #div2 does disappear (i.e. the red square isn't visible anymore). Any idea why?

Comment: Please make a Stack snippet.

Comment: Stack snippets added.

Answer (score 1):

Floating an Element will take this element out of the flow of the non-floating elements. But the TEXT of these other elements will be floated around the floating elements. Try to make your div2 larger and put some more text into it, then you see what I mean.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.